# Why variation of constant work to solve first order ODE?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y'(x)+a(x)y(x)=p(x)$ a first order ODE. To solve it, we first find a solution of the homogeneous equation $y'(x)+a(x)y(x)=0$. Let $y_1(x)=Ck(x)$ a solution. Now, to find the solution of the general eqution $y'(x)+a(x)y(x)=p(x)$, we say that $C=C(x)$ is a function, we replace $C(x)k(x)$ in the original equation, and we get on ODE of the form $C'(x)=t(x)$. At the end we can find $C(x)$ and thus the solution.

My question is : this method a bit magical, I don't really understand why it work. I always apply the method, but I don't really understand why it really works. Why this method works ? What is the theory behind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This $$ y'(x)+a(x)y(x)=p(x)$$ is a linear equation. One standard method to solving this equation is to multiply by an integrating factor and then integrate both sides.

The integrating factor is $$e^{\int a(x) dx}$$ and upon multiplying both sides we get $$ (y'(x)+a(x)y(x))e^{\int a(x) dx}   = e^{\int a(x) dx}  p(x)$$

The LHS is a total derivative  namely $$\frac {d}{dx} ( y(x)e^{\int a(x) dx})$$ so upon integration we come up with  $$y(x)e^{\int a(x) dx}=\int  e^{\int a(x) dx}  p(x) +c$$

To find $y(x)$ we multiply both sides by $$e^{\int -a(x) dx}$$ which is the solution to the homogeneous equation.

Therefore the particular solution is the product of the homogeneous solution by a function that you called $C(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why do you say that $y'+a(x)y(x)=b(x)$ is a linear ODE ? Is it a linear map or something like that ?$

Comment: @user623855 It's linear with respect to $y$ and the derivatives of $y$

Comment: @Dylan: what do you mean ?

Comment: @user623855 Read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation?wprov=sfla1